# How can I write a function that returns the score of a four-player game in the form of a tuple, where the original order of play is held throughout?

Tags: python, list, function, iteration, tuples

In an imaginary game, where four players (and only four) each roll a die, the player who rolls the largest number wins the round. This player receives `1` point, and they start the next round.

The original scores are represented as such: `(0, 0, 0, 0)` where the first element is the score of the person who starts the first round of the game, the second element is the player who rolls second in the first round, and so on.

I want to write a function that is able to "clock up" the scores of each player, whereafter the final round it will return their scores with the original order in tact. We can assume that no two people roll the same number in one round.

It will take the rounds as a list of tuples, for example:

```
scores([(1, 3, 4, 6),(3, 5, 2, 1),(6, 3, 4, 2)])
>>> (2, 0, 0, 1)

scores([(6, 2, 3, 1),(5, 2, 3, 1),(6, 3, 2, 4),(4, 3, 2, 1)])
>>> (4, 0, 0, 0)
```

Note that the order of the final scores is correspondent with the first round.
(Imagine four people sitting in a circle, and if the third player wins the first round, they would start the second round, followed by the fourth player etc.)

Comment: Your question/algorithm is not clear

Comment: are you asking a question??

Comment: How do I write the function that will give the returns in the example?

Answer (score 1):

```
def sumScores (scores):
    points = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    winner = 0
    for score in scores:
        winner = (winner + max(enumerate(score), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]) % 4
        points[winner] += 1
    return points
```

```
>>> sumScores([(1, 3, 4, 6),(3, 5, 2, 1),(6, 3, 4, 2)])
[2, 0, 0, 1]
>>> sumScores([(6, 2, 3, 1),(5, 2, 3, 1),(6, 3, 2, 4),(4, 3, 2, 1)])
[4, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Could you please explain what line 5 is doing? Thank you!

Comment: `max(…)[0]` will find the index in `score` for which the item has the highest value. That index is then added to the previous winner index and the modulo 4 gives the new winner index.

Comment: killer one liner...loved this :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be using using a dictionary. Have a dict like:-

`{'Player1':[],'Player2':[],'Player3':[],'Player4':[]}`.

After the 1st round, state of your dict will be

`{'Player1':[1],'Player2':[3],'Player3':[4],'Player4':[6]}`.

Now, no matter where the 2nd round starts, you append the score to the right list. So after 2nd round your dict would be like

`{'Player1':[1, 5],'Player2':[3, 2],'Player3':[4, 1],'Player4':[6, 3]}` ....and so on(I am considering the scores given in your question statement).

Now you can use `zip` on the lists, so you would get `[(1,3,4,6), (5, 2, 1, 3)]`. And this is indexed the way you wanted. 1st element in the tuple corresponds to Player1.

Answer (score 0):

```
def scores(s):
    tally = [0,0,0,0]
    for rnd in s:
        tally[rnd.index(max(rnd))] += 1
    return tuple(tally)
```

This awards a point to the first player in turn if there's a tie. If a ties need to be handled differently, you'll need a more complicated solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try a dictionary

```
#An initial dictionary of the cases for scoring
pl_dict = {'pl1': [1,0,0,0]. 'pl2': [0,1,0,0], 'pl3': [0,0,1,0], 'pl4': [0,0,0,1]}

#the dictionary that will store the scores for the game
score_dict = {0: (0,0,0,0)}

def score(player):
    #find the most recent round by looking at the dictionary keys
    max_rnd = max(list(score_dict.keys()))

    #do a list comprehension to make the new score array
    new_score = [x+y for x,y in zip(list(score_dict[max_rnd],pl_dict[player])

    #turn the list into a tuple and add it to a new round key in the dictionary
    score_dict[max_rnd+1] = tuple(new_score)
```

This keeps track of the rounds as the keys of `score_dict` are the round number. The function `score` calls for the player that scored to add the point to their position.